# how to add constraint dynamically in postgresql table using c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am cloning database table in postgresql using c#.now I also want to add constraints to newly created table.

can anyone suggest way to add constraints dynamically?

I want to add all constraints from table I've clone

thanks

Comment: could you clarify, why do you want to do this in C#? what to you mean by 'clone table'?

Comment: I am creating table using inheritance via c# code.so now after inheriting table I also want to add constraints from base table - from which I am inheriting another table - so how can I add constraint dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean postgresql inheritance, and you just executing SQL code from c#?

Comment: Yes I am executing code from c#

Comment: you can generate scripts by yourself - `select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = 'cities' and constraint_type in ('PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY')`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
  FROM pg_constraint
 WHERE conrelid = (select oid from pg_class where relname = ?)
```

where ? is the table name you are copying the constraints from.  You will then get a list of check, unique, and key constraints and you can decide what to copy in your application.  These are in definition form so you will see rows like:

```
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

and

```
 FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES other_table (id)
```